# Iframe form not getting submitted to its action URL rather getting submitted to browser window URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring

I have an iframe which I am populating using ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "inbox/search",
        data: dataToSend,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (serverResponse) {
            //server response came write this to iframe

            var ifrm = document.getElementById('contentframe');
            ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
            ifrm.document.open();
            ifrm.document.write(serverResponse);//server response written
            ifrm.document.close();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            removeThrobber();
            alert("Ajax Request Failed!Text Status:" + textStatus + ",errorThrown:" + errorThrown);
        }

    });
```

This newly populated iframe contain form tag with action

```
<form name="inboxSearchForm" id="inboxSearchForm" commandName="userQueueFilter" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/inbox/search" method="post">
<a href="#" id="nextPage" onclick="pageJump(document.getElementById('pageNum').value,'up') ">Next ></a>
</form>
```

There is a link(called Next) inside iframe which submit form using javascript

```
document.getElementById('inboxSearchForm').submit();
```

On click of link request `http://localhost:8080/Proj/inbox/search` is getting aborted automatically and firebug show request submission to new URL "`http://localhost:8080/Proj/landing`" This is the URL of Home page which contain this entire stuff .This URL is located at browser URL bar.Any idea about this behavior?